# codeigniter dynamically passing page url not working after page reload

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

in my codeigniter website, i have created a products page and display products in it using the category name in the url:

```html
<?php foreach($category as $cat): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>homecontroller/products/<?php echo $cat->name;?>"><?php echo $cat->name;?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

this is working fine.
now to filter the products i did the following in my controller :

```html
public function products()
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $material = $this->input->post('material1');       
    $material2 = $this->input->post('material2');
    $data['products'] = $this->product->findAll($id,$material,$material2);
    $this->load->view('products', $data);
}
```

my model:

```html
function findAll($id,$material,$material2)
{
    $this->db->where('cname', $id);
    if(!empty($material) || !empty($material2)) {
        $this->db->or_where('material', $material);
        $this->db->or_where('material', $material2);
    }
    return $this->db->get('product')->result();
}
```

and my filter product view:

```html
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>products" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="material1" value="cotton" class="form-check-input filled-in" id="new" onChange="this.form.submit()">
<input type="checkbox" name="material2" value="polyster" class="form-check-input filled-in" id="used" onChange="this.form.submit()">
</form>
```

here the problem is when a user select the filter option the page reloads and does the filter fine but the url becomes my base url/products which makes the product page to display all products without category, can anyone please tell me how to fix this, thanks in advance

Comment: The most important part is missing, the form for the material filters.

Answer (score 1):

try to use site_url instead of base_url in your view,base_url returns the base URL from your configuration site_url give a correct URL with index.php

```
  <form action="<?php= site_url('homecontroller/products')?>" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="material1" value="cotton" class="form-check-input filled-in" id="new" onChange="this.form.submit()">
<input type="checkbox" name="material2" value="polyster" class="form-check-input filled-in" id="used" onChange="this.form.submit()">
</form>
```

try to use it here also

```
<?php foreach($category as $cat){?>
    <li><a href="<?= site_url('homecontroller/products/'.$cat->name)?>"><?= $cat->name;?></a></li>
    <?php }?>
```

you should consider retrieving the passed values in the URL as a function parameter like this

note that when your form is submitted you don't send a value to your products function parameter
and that causes the error
**too few arguments to function Homecontroller::products(), 0 passed**

you can solve this by

```
public function products($productName = null)
{
     $id = $productName;
     $material = $this->input->post('material1');       
     $material2 = $this->input->post('material2');
     $data['products'] = $this->product->findAll($id,$material,$material2);
     $this->load->view('products', $data);
}
```

I hope it solves your problem

Comment: bro, how do we get this variable $productName

Comment: We passed it in the url and get it as method parameter if you look to your link it's look like this domain/controller/method/variable

Comment: bro i tried your code but i get the following error Too few arguments to function Homecontroller::products(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: did you try to make the product function parameter equal to null 
like this $productName = null

Comment: but bro then the url is changing from http://localhost/shopping/index.php/homecontroller/products/TESTS1 to http://localhost/shopping/index.php/homecontroller/products

Comment: you try to access the products function from two places from form when you submitted and you don't pass a value in the function parameter and the second way is the  link so if you don't want to get this error again you should make the parameter value equal to null 
if this solution causes problems you should make another function to handle the link

Answer (score 0):

Also try

```
<form method="post">
```

without action attribute to keep current url.